# How to re-compute symmetric key with ECDH implementation in .net framework 4.7 and up?

Tags: .net, cryptography, ecdh

1. Party A has ECC cert (along with its private key)
2. Party A sends this ECC cert to Party B
3. Party B computes ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey from this cert

   ```
   var cert = new X509Certificate2(certBytes);
   var bytesWithFormatIndicator = cert.PublicKey.EncodedKeyValue.RawData;
   var bytesWithoutFormatIndicator = bytesWithFormatIndicator.Skip(1).ToArray();
   var preBytes = "45434b3120000000".HexToBytes();   // First 8 bytes are specific to elliptic curve P-256
   var rawBytes = bytesWithoutFormatIndicator;
   var fullBytes = new byte[preBytes.Length + rawBytes.Length];
   Buffer.BlockCopy(preBytes, 0, fullBytes, 0, preBytes.Length);
   Buffer.BlockCopy(rawBytes, 0, fullBytes, preBytes.Length, rawBytes.Length);

   ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey senderPublicKey = ECDiffieHellmanCngPublicKey.FromByteArray(fullBytes, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
   ```
4. Party B creates ECDH implementation (i.e. ephemeral public and private key pair)

   ```
   var ecdhReceiver = ECDiffieHellman.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256);
   ```
5. Party B used above ECDH implementation along with Party A ECC cert public key (and some prepend and append bytes) and computes symmetric key

   ```
   var prependBytes = "00000001".HexToBytes();
   var appendBytes = "00000002".HexToBytes();
   var derivedSymmetricKey = ecdhReceiver.DeriveKeyFromHash(senderPublicKey, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, prependBytes, appendBytes);
   ```
6. Party B sends the ephemeral public key (from above ECDH implementation) to Party A

   ```
   var ephemeralKeyBytesWithoutFormat = ecdhReceiver.PublicKey.ToByteArray().Skip(8).ToArray()
   ```
7. The goal for Party A now is to compute the same symmetric key using Party B's ephemeral public key and Party A's ECC cert (and its private key).

I am stuck at (7). Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be easier than I thought:

1) Party A can dump out private and public key info from open ssl command.

```
    openssl ec -in chris\key.pem -text -noout
```

2) Party A gets the output that will look like following.

```
    Private-Key: (256 bit)
    priv:
        36:aa:94:67:66:2c:c5:3a:6b:44:da:af:2b:af:69:
        eb:83:e1:f6:b2:43:52:b5:b4:82:4f:bb:a7:64:71:
        68:3f
    pub:
        04:e7:b2:14:ce:a1:66:0a:2f:1f:3d:5e:af:95:be:
        e4:4b:00:27:fd:1a:06:f7:14:10:88:2a:ed:2c:51:
        1b:54:13:16:3e:05:f5:5b:bc:48:30:4a:49:32:46:
        7f:ca:fe:cc:b1:a0:09:91:6b:fd:8f:01:7f:41:ba:
        35:50:6e:a4:da
    ASN1 OID: prime256v1
    NIST CURVE: P-256
```

3) Party A constructs ECDH implementation with the above info (the leading byte 0x04 in the public key is a format indicator, ignore it):

```
    var ecParamsReceiver = new ECParameters
    {
        Curve = ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256,
        D = "36aa9467662cc53a6b44daaf2baf69eb83e1f6b24352b5b4824fbba76471683f".HexToBytes(),
        Q = new ECPoint()
        {
            X = "e7b214cea1660a2f1f3d5eaf95bee44b0027fd1a06f71410882aed2c511b5413".HexToBytes(),
            Y = "163e05f55bbc48304a4932467fcafeccb1a009916bfd8f017f41ba35506ea4da".HexToBytes(),
        }
    };
    ecParamsReceiver.Validate();
    var receiverEcdh = ECDiffieHellman.Create(ecParamsReceiver);
```

4) Party A constructs Party B public key from the Party B ephemeral public key

```
    var senderEphemeralPublicKey = ephemeralKeyBytesWithoutFormat;
    var ecParams = new ECParameters
    {
        Curve = ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256,
        Q = new ECPoint()
        {
            X = senderEphemeralPublicKey.Take(senderEphemeralPublicKey.Length / 2).ToArray(),
            Y = senderEphemeralPublicKey.Skip(senderEphemeralPublicKey.Length / 2).Take(senderEphemeralPublicKey.Length / 2).ToArray(),
        }
    };
    ecParams.Validate();
    var senderEcdh = ECDiffieHellman.Create(ecParams);
```

5) Party A uses the same prepend and append bytes to compute the same symmetric key

```
    var prependBytes = "00000001".HexToBytes();
    var appendBytes = "00000002".HexToBytes();
    var derivedSymmetricKey = receiverEcdh.DeriveKeyFromHash(senderEcdh.PublicKey, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, prependBytes, appendBytes);
```